# Get downloadable url from github zipball url

Tags: php, wordpress, github

```
if ( is_null( $this->github_response ) ) { // Do we have a response?
        $request_uri = sprintf( 'https://api.github.com/repos/%s/%s/releases', $this->username, $this->repository ); // Build URI

        if( $this->authorize_token ) { // Is there an access token?
           /* $request_uri = add_query_arg( 'access_token', $this->authorize_token, $request_uri ); // Append it*/



            $basicauth = 'token ' . $this->authorize_token;
            $headers = array( 
                    'Authorization' => $basicauth
            );
        }

        $pload = array(
            'headers' => $headers
            );
        $response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $request_uri, $pload ) ), true ); // Get JSON and parse it

        if( is_array( $response ) ) { // If it is an array
            $response = current( $response ); // Get the first item
        }

        if( $this->authorize_token ) { // Is there an access token?
            $response['zipball_url'] = add_query_arg( 'access_token', $this->authorize_token, $response['zipball_url'] ); // Update our zip url with token
        }

        $this->github_response = $response; // Set it to our property
    }
```

My target is to get the downloadable url from the latest git release. I also get the downloadable url with this code. But the problem is github send me an email about deprecated issue: Deprecating API authentication through query parameters.

I read the doc of github but could not solve it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Also interested in this.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to update the code and send the token in the header?

Comment: Yeah I was able to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I got to this point in the cURL request:

```php
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $request_uri,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Authorization: token " . $this->authorize_token,
        "User-Agent: My App Name Here"
    ]
]);
```

But if I comment out this line:

```php
// if ($this->authorize_token) {
//     $response['zipball_url'] = add_query_arg('access_token', $this->authorize_token, $response['zipball_url']);
// }
```

I get a "Not found" error.

Answer (score -1):

GitHub is deprecating access to the API using the `access_token` query parameter.  The problem with this approach is that it causes tokens to be logged in various logs (not GitHub's, but pretty much everyone else's), which is a huge security problem.

If you want to make an API request, you should pass the token in the `Authorization` header in the form `token TOKEN`, where `TOKEN` is your token value, and *not at all* in the URL.  In your code, you're adding the `access_token` parameter to the zipball URL, which you should not; you should use an `Authorization` header, like you did for the initial request.  You should also be prepared to follow redirects if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I understand the procedure but could not cope up with the code. Could you please have a look at my code and let me know how I can make it done?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with PHP.  I can tell what's wrong with your code and I'm very familiar with this aspect of GitHub's implementation, but I don't know how to write PHP to fix your code without a bunch of research and a full set of working code.